# Is this a correct way of declaring an array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have to make an array of whole numbers K(L) (L<=30) in c++,and i need some help declarating it correctly ,because im certain my way is wrong.

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    const int L = 30;
    void main ()
     {
       int K[L]
       int br =0;
       int i;
       for (i = 0; i < L; i++)
       cout <<endl << "Enter a number" ;
       cin >> K[i];
       }
```

Comment: *Why* are you certain that your way is wrong?

Comment: _Using_ an array is normally not what you want to do, `void main()` is wrong, but your array definition is perfectly legal C++.

Comment: You array declaration is fine. However, the `cin >> K[i];` statement will be run _only once_, with `i=L`, which will go past the end of the array and cause undefined behavior. Perhaps you meant to wrap the `cout`/`cin` statements in braces `{}` to include them in the body of the `for`-loop?

Comment: Well someone told me that i have a lot of mistakes.Why is void main () wrong ?

Comment: @bashtati _"Why is void main () wrong ?"_ Because the c++ standard demands `main()` to return an `int`.

Comment: Declaring main as void is not wrong for a quick one-off program.  You should prefer the int main() for code you are releasing.

Comment: @Jim It's blatantly wrong. That the MSVC compiler still supports that is completely irrelevant.

Comment: Then, shalt thou declare `main()` returning `int`, no more, no less. `int` shalt be the thype thou shalt use, and the thype thou shalt use shall be `int`.

Comment: I stand corrected.  My apologies to any folks I have led astray.

Comment: Or more properly, according to C++11, *It shall have a return type of type `int`, but otherwise its type is implementation-defined. All implementations shall allow both of the following definitions of `main`:
`int main() { /* ... */ }`
and
`int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { /* ... */ }`*. Wording may have changed a bit in subsequent Standard revisions. See **[basic.start.main]**

Comment: [Link to freely available draft close to C++11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.start.main). And a [link to more recent wording](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.main)

Answer (score 11):

The first error the compiler gives is pretty self-explanatory:

```
main.cpp:4:16: error: ‘::main’ must return ‘int’
     void main ()
                ^
```

The next two are trickier. They are caused by the forgotten `;` on the `int K[L]` line.

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:7:8: error: expected initializer before ‘int’
        int br =0;
        ^~~
main.cpp:11:15: error: ‘K’ was not declared in this scope
        cin >> K[i];
```

The forgotten `;` makes the compiler read the line as `int K[L] int br =0;` so the declaration of both `K` and `br` fails, and it's the failed declaration of `K` that causes the third error.

I corrected it and removed an oddly placed std::endl.

```
#include <iostream>

const int L = 30;

int main()
{
    int K[L];
    // int br =0; // unused
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < L; i++) {
        std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
        std::cin >> K[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your array declaration is simply missing a semicolon.

Use `int K[L];` instead of `int K[L]`.